# How to set a method that hides a ModalPopupExtender when a button is clicked?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have this `modal`:

```
<asp:ModalPopupExtender runat="server" ID="popUp" TargetControlID="btn1" PopupControlID="pnlP" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" DropShadow="true" />
```

With this `updatePanel`:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="pnlP" runat="server" Width="600" Height="650">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Label Text="Hola" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnCerrarPopUp" runat="server" OnClick="ocultarModal" Text="Adios!" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

What I´m trying to do is to create a **unic method that hides a ModalPopupExtender when a button inside the panel showed by the ModalPopupExtender is clicked**, so if I have "N" ModalPopupExtender with a button that hides it **I will always call the same method** no matter which ModalPopupExtender -> panel -> button is clicked.

How can I identify which `ModalPopupExtender` should hide?

```
protected void ocultarModal(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Identify which ModalPopupExtender should hide
    // thatModal.Hide();
}
```

Remmember that I have a lot of `ModalPopupExtender` that show a `panel` that has a `button` that must **call the same method to hide that ModalPopupExtender**.

Help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the OnClick, use the OnCommand, passing the Modal Identifier as a command argument. Then, in the Code-Behind, retrive the argument from the OnCommand event and close the modal using the appropriate ModalPopupExtender. Below is an example:

```
<asp:ModalPopupExtender runat="server" ID="popUp1" TargetControlID="btn1" PopupControlID="pnlP" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" DropShadow="true" />


<asp:UpdatePanel ID="pnlP" runat="server" Width="600" Height="650">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Label Text="Hola" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnCerrarPopUp" runat="server" OnCommand="ocultarModalCommand" CommandArgument="popUp1" Text="Adios!" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

You can see above the modal popup extender and the update panel for the Modal 1. Here instead of using OnClick, OnCommand was used, and as its CommandArgumkent, the id of the modal popup extender was set: "popUp1".

How, have a look at the listener below:

```
protected void ocultarModalCommand(Object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    // Identify which ModalPopupExtender should hide
    String extenderId = (String) e.CommandArgument;
    // hide popup 1
    if (extenderId.equals("popUp1") {
        popUp1.Hide();
    } else if (extender.equals("popUp2") {
        // hide popup2
    }
    // check all other modals

}
```

Above the command listener gets the name of the extender, which is set in the Command Argument. Based on that, it knows which Modal to close.

Moreover, you can do something fancier with the listener, like the code below:

```
protected void ocultarModalCommand(Object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    // Identify which ModalPopupExtender should hide
    String extenderId = (String) e.CommandArgument;
    // get the control based on its id
    ModalPopupExtender extender = (MOdalPopupExtender) FindControl(extenderId);
    if (extender != null)
    {
        extender.Hide();
    }
}
```

In the code above, you find the extender based on the Id set in the Command Argument. However, if the Id is wrongly set, null will be returned and nothing will be hidden. This code has the huge advantage of being much smaller than the previous one.

There you have it, a single event which can close all your Modals.

Comment: Hey I´m getting this error in String extenderId = e.CommandArgument;: Error 982 Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) I tried this: String extenderId = (String)e.CommandArgument;
        ModalPopupExtender extender = (ModalPopupExtender)FindControl(extenderId); but extender is always null. But why?

Comment: Regarding your first question. I've just updated the code: the `e.CommandArgument` needs a cast to String. About your second question: It returns null either because the Id is misspelled or because your extender is within another component, such as a panel, updtate panel, or something else. Thus you need to use the FindControl to first retrieve the outer control, and fetch the inner ones.

Comment: also remove the "" in the FindControl parameter

Comment: The id is correct so my error is in the second option. Should I have to change the parameter CommandArgument to look first for pnlP an then popUp? If so how to do that?

Comment: Suppose in your page you have a Panel (called p1), another Panel within that called p2 and then your extender called popUp. So you would have to do as follows: Panel p1 = (Panel) FindControl("p1"); Panel p2 = (Panel) p1.FindControl("p2"); ModalPopupExtender extender = (MOdalPopupExtender) p2.FindControl("popUp");. Remember that you can always use the first option, with lots of ifs :).

Comment: The first option works but dont give me the dynamic that I want. So this is how my form is: asp:Content ID="BodyContent"--div class="main2"--Then the code above as it appears. Can you help me with that, to do it as your example please?

Comment: You would have to do as follows: Content c = (Content) FindControl("BodyContent"); ModalPopupExtender extender = (MOdalPopupExtender) c.FindControl("popUp");. You can use the debug to see the tree of controls and find where your extender is. The idea is to follow the hierarchical order of the controls. Let me know if it works.

Comment: The c object is null so extender is null too. I think I´ll use option 1, I just dont wanted to be modifying that method each time I add a modal in the form. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you could post your aspx and code behind, I would create an app with that and post the entire solution.

Comment: Can´t do that. I am maintaining a system someone else developed and there are more than a thousand lines in the file. I just dont like to see the same code everywhere, that makes it difficult to read and difficult to maintain. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I see what you're saying. But if you could build up a small sample, holding the structure and only one Modal, I could give the whole answer.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using JavaScript. The popup element ends with the `_foregroundElement` suffix, so you can easily get it with jQuery (ends with ID selector for an element that is a parent of the button).

Then, strip away the `_foregroundElement` part and use `$find(theRemainingPartOfTheString)`

WIth this, you have a reference to the client-side object of the control, regardless of its actual ID or buton.

Then, call its `hide()` method and you are done. Removing the postback will make your page faster too :).